# OLS In Time Series

Tags: time-series, least-squares, mean

Assume $X_t=\beta+Y_t$, where $Y_t$ is a zero-mean stationary process and $\beta$ is a real constant (unknown).

How would I show that the least squares estimator of $\beta$ is given by $\bar{X}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer assumes that $y_t$ is not observable. The least squares estimator seeks to find the estimator $\hat{\beta}$ that minimized the sum of squared residuals, where the residual is defined as the difference between the actual value $x_t$ and its expectation $\beta$: $\epsilon_t = x_t - \beta$.

Finding the $\hat{\beta}$ that minimizes $\sum_t \epsilon_t^2 = \sum_t (x_t-\beta)^2$ will lead to $\hat{\beta} = \bar{x}_t$.

To get to this result expand the squares, take the first derivative with respect to $\beta$ and set it equal to zero, the $\beta$ that solves the equation is the least squares estimator.